# Brightness can only go 1 level lower/higher on Fedora 32

Tags: linux, fedora, amd-graphics, brightness

First, I have to say that I'm completely new to linux and Fedora. So, please tell me the steps needed if you need more details.

The problem is like this:
I'm on max brightness and then lower it by 1 level
Yes it went dimmer
But if I try to lower the brightness again, it just doesn't work
The animation plays, but the brightness stays the same
If increase the brightness again, it will only be brighter at the last level

If you still don't understand, here's a video of it https://uploadir.com/u/ifm5dm09

I've searched for "Fedora 32 can't change brightness" and tried the solution where you have to edit `etc/default/grub`. But that's only making it worst, the brightness cannot be changed after that (But i reversed the changes).

inxi -Fxmz:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.0.1 
  Console: tty 0 Distro: Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81W3 v: IdeaPad 3 14ARE05 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0Q55726WIN serial: <filter> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: DZCN23WW date: 07/14/2020 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 19.1 Wh condition: 45.8/45.7 Wh (100%) 
  model: Sunwoda L19D3PF5 status: Discharging 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 6.71 GiB used: 2.73 GiB (40.7%) 
  Array-1: capacity: 16 GiB slots: 2 EC: None max module size: 8 GiB 
  note: est. 
  Device-1: DIMM 0 size: 4 GiB speed: 3200 MT/s type: DDR4 
  Device-2: DIMM 0 size: 4 GiB speed: 3200 MT/s type: DDR4 
CPU:
  Info: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 
  type: MCP arch: Zen rev: 1 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 28445 
  Speed: 1383 MHz min/max: 1400/2375 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2264 2: 1371 
  3: 1624 4: 1406 5: 1384 6: 1397 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  bus ID: 03:00.0 
  Device-2: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus ID: 1-3:3 
  Display: server: Fedora Project X.org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu 
  note: display driver n/a resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: 
  renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.36.0 5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64 LLVM 10.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 03:00.1 
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A bus ID: 03:00.5 
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.6 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.6.6-300.fc32.x86_64 
Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb bus ID: 3-3:2 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 6.89 GiB (1.4%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital 
  model: PC SN530 SDBPMPZ-512G-1101 size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 135.08 GiB used: 6.72 GiB (5.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0 
  ID-2: /boot size: 968.3 MiB used: 161.5 MiB (16.7%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7 
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 9.77 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) 
  dev: /dev/dm-1 
Sensors:
  Message: No sensors data was found. Is sensors configured? 
Info:
  Processes: 344 Uptime: 34m Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
  gcc: 10.0.1 Packages: 1682 Shell: Bash v: 5.0.11 inxi: 3.1.06
```

Edit 1:
If I boot into Windows, restart, and then boot into Fedora, the brightness works!
But if I boot straight to Fedora, the problem occurs

I don't know why.
I'll try upgrading the kernel first as told in the comments.

Comment: This (not reliable) source https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/open-source-amd-linux/1189912-linux-5-8-bringing-some-performance-boosts-for-amd-renoir-graphics#post1190023 has a comment telling brightness bugs were fixed for AMD Renoir in kernel 5.8. I notice you are using kernel 5.6. You should consider upgrading to a newer version, 5.8.x or 5.9.x. Here's an example fix related to brightness (doesn't mean it's the one) in kernel 5.8: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-5.8.y&id=54dc92e1900895401135ffbc95586dae30309a14

Comment: https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2020-8c65b883c8

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, I'll try upgrading the kernel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I upgraded the Kernel to 5.8
Thanks to A.B in the comment for the answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/356249)

Comment: @Archemar generally true, but A.B. left only comments, not Answers, so the OP self-answered.